# USB Thumb drive with WiFi data store

Tags: wireless-networking, usb

Does anyone know of a USB thumb drive that will connect to a data store via wifi?

In other words...

I have a dvd player that shows photos off a USB thumb drive. I want to able to have the thumb drive connect via wifi to a share on a server instead of it's own memory.

Like this [device](http://www.adorama.com/ICDEYEFI8EX.html?utm_source=gbase&utm_medium=Shopping+Site&utm_campaign=Other&utm_term=Other) but different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess what you need is something like this : http://www.engadget.com/2010/08/01/infinitec-opens-pre-orders-for-infinite-usb-memory-drive-tout/ ...

Though, realistically, is it worth it?

Comment: Hot dog... I could just get a new apple tv for the price of that unit. But yes it would do the trick.

Comment: Well, basically that's what I thought. Extending old technology using new technology invariably cost more than buying new items that does both.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use one of those Eye-fi devices with one of [these](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000FNDWLQ) sd to usb adapters.

I haven't tried it myself so I don't know if it will work.

Comment: The Eye-fi device goes the wrong way. It would move data from it's memory to the server.